# Shuffling a large network using Python

Tags: python, list, hash, networkx, shuffle

I have a large network to analyze. For example:

```
import networkx as nx
import random

BA = nx.random_graphs.barabasi_albert_graph(1000000, 3)
nx.info(BA)
```

I have to shuffle the edges while keeping the degree distribution unchanged. The basic idea was introduced by [Maslov](http://www.cmth.bnl.gov/~maslov/matlab.htm). Thus, my colleague and I wrote a shuffleNetwork function in which we work on a network object G for num times. edges is a list object.

The problem is this function runs too slow for large networks. I tried to use *set* or *dict* instead of *list* for the edges object (set and dict are hash table). However, since we also need to delete and add elements to it, the *time complexity* becomes even bigger.

Do you have any suggestions on further optimising this function?

```
def shuffleNetwork(G,Num):
    edges=G.edges()
    l=range(len(edges))
    for n in range(Num):
        i,j = random.sample(l, 2)
        a,b=edges[i]
        c,d=edges[j]
        if a != d and c!= b:
            if not (a,d) in edges or (d, a) in edges or (c,b) in edges or (b, c) in edges:
                edges[i]=(a,d)
                edges[j]=(c,b)
    K=nx.from_edgelist(edges)
    return K



import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
#Your statements here
gr = shuffleNetwork(BA, 1000)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print stop - start
```

Comment: I've taken another look at your code.  I think the slow part is the testing if `(a,d) in edges` etc.  It's faster to do `if not G.has_edge(a,d)`.  Then rather than checking if `(a,d)` is in your list of edges (requiring a check for every single edge in your edgelist), it goes directly to `a` and checks if `d` is a neighbor.  This is O(1) (almost) versus O(len(edgelist)).  I suspect with this change your code will be comparable to `double_edge_swap`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should consider using `nx.double_edge_swap`

The documentation is [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.swap.double_edge_swap.html).  It looks like it does exactly what you want, but modifies the graph in place.

I'm not sure whether it will solve the speed issues, but it does avoid generating the list, so I think it will do better than what you've got.

You would call it with `nx.double_edge_swap(G,nswap=number)`

Comment: That's exactly what I need, although I still do not know how does it do it magically. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Check the source: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/swap.html#double_edge_swap  It uses `nx.utils`  to generate a cumulative distribution and then choose appropriately from that.  This lets it choose a node proportionally to its number of edges, then it chooses one of the edges of that node, so it is uniformly sampling the edges, but without having to generate the edge list.